# proc rank vs proc means to remove the top and bottom 0.1%

Tags: sas

I would like to remove some outlier in the top and bottom 0.1%. PROC MEANS has the p99 option which only helps to remove the top 1%, not 0.1%. Is there another way to do so? I thought of PROC RANK but not sure if it would give the same result. 
my code is:

```
    proc means data=input noprint; by date; output out=trunc(drop=_FREQ_ _TYPE_) p99(var1)=p99_var1 p99(var2)=p99_var2; run;
data input; merge input trunc; by date;
    if var1 < p99_var1 and var2<p99_var2;run;

    versus 

    proc rank data=input out=input percent;
        by date;
         var var1 var2;
         ranks percentile1 percentile2;
    run;
data input; set input; 
where 0.001<percentile1<0.999 and 0.001<percentile2<0.999;run
```

I am aware that in the first method I use 99% (because I don't know how to do 99.9% with this method) but I use 99.9% in the second method. If I use 99% for the second method, which one would be a better way to do? and would the 2 yield the same result?

Answer (score 2):

`proc means` only has access to certain default percentiles, however you can specify custom percentiles in `proc univariate`

```
proc univariate data=sashelp.prdsal3 noprint;
   var actual;
   output out=want pctlpre=P_ pctlpts=0.1,99.9;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the ties treatment and fractions options of proc rank you should have the flexibility you need for this problem.

Check the SAS documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146840.htm).